# How to have multiple web site with one URL?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have 2 web projects, with one URL: *www.theurl.com*, which is directed to the ISA server, behind this server  is a web server (windows 2003).

I have a default web site, and another web site which I want to add (website2). When the user clicks the URL, directly goes to my first web site.

How can I have for example: *www.theurl.com/website2* and how should I configure the IIS without using another port? I am using port:80

Thanks in advance

Comment: create a virtual directory? right click your website on iis control panel, you will one option called new -> virtual directory.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have the hostnames be the way to separate the sites?  That may be a way to do this, but that is in the bindings in IIS I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hostnames to allow IIS to filter and direct the requests based on site. See here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7f5d.jpg]